# $_GET['variable'] == 'text'

Tags: php, get, http-headers

I want to compare if a get variable is a specific text. But I cannot get into the if-statemeant. The echo "invalid user" is not written.

code:

```
<?php 
if ($_GET['status'] && $_GET['status'] == "login_fail") {
                        echo "invalid user";
                    }
?>
```

when I check the variable status before (ando also after) the if-statemeant with:

```
echo $_GET['status'];
```

or with

```
print_r($_GET['status']);
```

the result is in both

> login_fail

So the variable status is there and has `"login_fail"`.

But `"invalid user"` is not written!

I tried it also with `===` or with ' instead " and much much more.

Comment: Try changing the first condition to `isset($_GET['status'])`

Comment: can u show me pint_r($_GET) result

Comment: it is login_fail
thats why i not understand ...

Comment: you may also try this array_key_exists('status', $_GET);

Comment: Thanks all, problem was the isset I forgot!

Works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use isset().

`

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == "login_fail") {
    echo "invalid useenter code herer";
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == "login_fail") {
  echo "invalid user";
}
?>
```

Comment: !empty is required here to avoid any notice error, if $_GET doesn't contain any param set as `status`, NOTICE will definitely be thrown there.

Comment: This is a very common requirement which only needs a little code experience to know it. Anyway you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876868/php-get-and-undefined-index for the requirement of isset() or !empty() check.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code don't have any problem. 
if your facing a problem till now you can add this line
before your if condition script.
$_GET['status'] = trim($_GET['status']);

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid errors when $_GET has nothing, use this:

```
if (!empty($_GET['status']) && ($_GET['status'] == "login_fail")) {
   echo "invalid user";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `isset()` function to check whether a variable has any value:

```
if(isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == 'login_fail')
{
    echo "invalid user";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to test if 'status' is set in the $_GET variable first and then check its value.

```
if (isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == "login_fail") 
{
   echo "invalid user";
}
```

That way you will not run into any problems if it's not set.