# undefined variable while updating

Tags: php

Here my aim to update a book's information with title which I set in the textbox. But in my code I when I run I'm getting the error as `$query2` is undefined in `$query2['status']=="Available"`. Can anyone rectify my error?

```
<?php
$user="root";
$server="localhost";
$password="";
$db="library book";
$query=mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
$dbRes = mysql_select_db($db,$query);

if(isset($_GET['book_id']))
{
    $bookid = $_GET['book_id'];
    $str="select * from books where bookid=$bookid";
$query1=mysql_query($str);
//echo $query1;
$query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
//print_r ($query2);
}
if(isset($_POST['Update']))
{
$title=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
        $author=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
        $publisher=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['publisher']);
        $numcopies=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['numcopies']);
        $shelfno=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shelfno']);
        $status=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
        $str1="update books set title=$title where bookid=$bookid";
        $query3=mysql_query($str1);
        echo $query3;
        $query4=mysql_query("select * from books");
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($query3);
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><th>BookID</th><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Publisher</th><th>numcopies</th><th>shelfno</th><th>status</th><th>Action</th></tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['bookid']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['author']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['publisher']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['numcopies']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['shelfno']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['status']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
if ($query2['status']=="Available") 
echo "selected";
if ($query2['status']=="Unavailable") 
echo "selected";
}


?>



<html>
<head><title>Editing the fields</title>
<style>
body {
background-color: rgb(255,0,255);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="edit1.php" action="post">

EnterTitle:<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $query2['title'];?>">
<br/>
EnterAuthor:<input type="text" name="author" value="<?php echo $query2['author'];?>" >
<br/>
EnterPublisher:<input type="text" name="publisher" value="<?php echo $query2['publisher'];?>">
<br/>
EnterNumCopies:<input type="text" name="numcopies" value="<?php echo $query2['numcopies'];?>">
<br/>
EnterShelfNo:<input type="text" name="shelfno" value="<?php echo $query2['shelfno'];?>">
<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="bookid" value=<?php if(isset($bookid)) echo $bookid; ?>>
<select>
<option value="available" <?php if ($query2['status']=="Available") echo "selected";?>>Available</option>
<option value="unavailable" <?php if ($query2['status']=="Unavailable") echo "selected";?>>Unavailable</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `mysqli` or `pdo` extension. `mysql` extension is deprecated.

Comment: Side note, don't do this, `$bookid = $_GET['book_id']; $str="select * from books where bookid=$bookid";`. It's an easy way for your database to be wiped out.

Comment: you should send book id in post. use input type has hide and search again to get $query2 because  when you submit page it will refresh page and that time you get $_POST value not $_GET so it will not go into $_GET condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php $\_GET and undefined index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876868/php-get-and-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1):

I think unfortunately, what you have going on here is the beginnings of a ["spaghetti code"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) syndrome so you will want to invest in learning a PHP [framework](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/). You will have less chance of security issues, your script will be cleaner from the get-go, more-easily maintained, etc.

For this particular snippet, among other things, you have [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) issues, you set `bookid` by `$_GET` and `$_POST` but it's hard to determine which is best to use, you have html happening above the `<html>` tag, but the main problem you are experiencing is that you have variables that are defined in an `if` scope but are also referenced outside of that `if` scope so will create the error(s) when the `if` condition is not satisfied ([See this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876868/php-get-and-undefined-index/7876945) for more reference).

**Some suggestions besides fixing the scope issue:**

1. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_` with parameter binding. My example uses [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
2. Use [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) or [class/method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) for both usability and readability in your final layout *(it looks more complex as I have it below, but only because it's all pasted on one page. Each page should be separate)*. All of this `$query`, `$query1`, `$query2`, etc. gets confusing. I have used functions, but a class would have been better to pass `bookid` to all the methods internally.
3. Standardize your book id key name, either make it `book_id` or `bookid`, not both. My example uses `bookid`.

There are probably some flaws in this, but hopefully it gives you some useful ideas and as I said before, this would be more useful implemented as a class (a few classes actually) but using functions might be a good start to help clean your scripting up.

*IMPORTANT NOTE: I have not tested this (there should be no syntax errors though) but you should be able to get the idea about what is happening and what things are for by paralleling your version to this one. If you don't understand it, read up on it first, don't blindly copy and paste or you will get into more trouble. Use at your own risk, as they say.*

**/functions/getBooks.php**

```
# Create a general function to fetch all books.
function getBooks($con)
    {
        $result = array();
        $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM books");
        $query->execute();
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

**/functions/getBookById.php**

```
# Create a function to fetch a specific book by id
function getBookById($id,$con)
    {
        $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM books WHERE bookid = :id");
        $query->execute(array(":id"=>$id));
        $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return (!empty($row))? $row : array();
    }
```

**/functions/getBook.php**

```
# This should fetch from a global request, that way you can tell if
# a book is currently being accessed
function getBook($con)
    {
        autoload(array('getBookById','getId'));
        $id = getId('req');
        if(empty($id))
            return false;

        return getBookById($id,$con);
    }
```

**/functions/updateBookById.php**

```
# Create an update function that can be accessed at anytime. Use binding
# so you don't need to mess with any sort of escaping
function updateBookById($id,$values,$con)
    {
        foreach($values as $keys => $vals) {
            $bKey = ":{$keys}";
            $bind[$bKey] = $vals;
            $sql[] = '`'.$key.'` = '.$bKey;
        }
        $bind[":id"] = $id;
        $query = $con->prepare("UPDATE books SET ".implode(', ',$sql)." WHERE bookid = :id");
        $query->execute($bind);
    }
```

**/functions/updateBookTitle.php**

```
# This is is just a specific function to focus on title. Not sure you need
# it since the update book by id function would do the same thing
function updateBookTitle($id,$title,$con)
    {
        $bind[":id"] = $id;
        $bind[":title"] = $title;
        $query = $con->prepare("UPDATE books SET title = :title WHERE bookid = :id");
        $query->execute($bind);
    }
```

**/functions/getId.php**

```
# This will fetch the id value from a global
function getId($type = false)
    {
        switch($type) {
            case('post'):
                return (isset($_POST['bookid']))? $_POST['bookid'] : false;
            case('req'):
                return (isset($_REQUEST['bookid']))? $_REQUEST['bookid'] : false;
            default:
                return (isset($_GET['bookid']))? $_GET['bookid'] : false;
        }
    }
```

**/functions/bookObserver.php**

```
# This will sit and just wait for the right globals activate it
function bookObserver($con,&$curr)
    {
        autoload('getId');
        if(getId('req')) {
            autoload('getBookById');
            $books = getBookById(getId('req'),$con);
            if(!empty($books))
                $curr = $books;

            if(isset($_POST['Update'])) {
                $values = array(
                    'title' => $_POST['title'],
                    'author' => $_POST['author'],
                    'publisher' => $_POST['publisher'],
                    'numcopies' => $_POST['numcopies'],
                    'shelfno' => $_POST['shelfno'],
                    'status' => $_POST['status']
                );
                autoload('updateBookById');
                updateBookById(getId('req'),$values,$con);
            }
        }
    }
```

**/functions/bookListObserver.php**

```
# This sits and waits for the update to write the table to the page
function bookListObserver($current,$con)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['Update'])) {
            autoload('bookList');
            echo bookList(((!empty($current['status']))? $current['status'] : false),$con);
        }
    }
```

**/functions/getValue.php**

```
# This will just check if a value is set. Saves on scripting
function getValue($array,$key,$def = false)
    {
        return (!empty($array[$key]))? $array[$key] : $def;
    }
```

**/functions/bookList.php**

```
# Displays your book list. Currently you are only showing the last book, 
# which doesn't appear correct. No point in getting all books but only showing
# the last one
function bookList($selected = false,$con)
    {
        autoload('getBooks');
        $books = getBooks($con);
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>BookID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Publisher</th>
                <th>numcopies</th>
                <th>shelfno</th>
                <th>status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        <?php foreach($books as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['title'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['author'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['publisher'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['numcopies'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['shelfno'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['status'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </table>
        <?php
        if($selected == "Available") 
            echo "selected";
        elseif($selected == "Unavailable") 
            echo "selected";

        $data = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $data;
    }
```

**/functions/connect.php**

```
# This is your mysql connection, it requires attention to build out
# It's not as useful as it could be, so you will want to research it
function connect()
    {
        return new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
    }
```

**/functions/autoload.php**

```
# This is just a handy function to autoload functions when you want
# to use them. If you used classes, you would make an spl_autoload_register()
# function or install something like Composer to autoload
function autoload($name,$run = false)
    {
        if(is_array($name)) {
            foreach($name as $func) {
                autoload($func);
            }
            return;
        }

        if(!function_exists($name)) {
            if(is_file($file = FUNCTIONS.DS.$name.'.php'))
                include_once($file);
        }

        if($run) {
            if(function_exists($name))
                return $name();
        }
    }
```

**/config.php**

```
# Make sure errors are on in testing
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
# Creating commonly-used defines will help your scripts be
# more reliable and consistent
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__);
define('FUNCTIONS',ROOT_DIR.DS.'functions');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','library book');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','');
# Start session by default
session_start();
require_once(FUNCTIONS.DS.'autoload.php');
# Autoload the connect function and assign it
$con = autoload('connect',true);
```

**/index.php**

```
<?php
# Add config
include(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');
# Include all our starting page functions
autoload(array('bookObserver','bookListObserver','getBook', 'getValue'));
# Set default array for current selection
$current = array();
# Start observer, pass connection
bookObserver($con,$current);
?>
<html>
<head><title>Editing the fields</title>
<style>
body {
background-color: rgb(255,0,255);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
# This writes the table if update is set
# You should not put this html above the <html> tag
bookListObserver($current,$con);
# This gets the book from the page request
$book = getBook($con);
?>
<form action="edit1.php" action="post">
    EnterTitle:<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo getValue($book,'title') ?>"><br/>
    EnterAuthor:<input type="text" name="author" value="<?php echo getValue($book,'author') ?>" ><br/>
    EnterPublisher:<input type="text" name="publisher" value="<?php echo getValue($book,'publisher') ?>"><br/>
    EnterNumCopies:<input type="text" name="numcopies" value="<?php echo getValue($book,'numcopies') ?>"><br/>
    EnterShelfNo:<input type="text" name="shelfno" value="<?php echo getValue($book,'shelfno') ?>"><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="bookid" value="<?php echo getValue($book,'bookid') ?>" />
    <select>
        <option value="available" <?php if(isset($current['status']) && $current['status'] == "Available") echo "selected";?>>Available</option>
        <option value="unavailable" <?php if (isset($current['status']) && $current['status'] == "Unavailable") echo "selected";?>>Unavailable</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```