# What could be wrong with $_GET in my code?

Tags: php, html

```
<html>
<body>
```

//the GET Method

```
Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>`enter code here`
<html>
<body>
```

//the Form html code

```
<form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

error

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp64\www\FMS\welcome.php on line 4 
Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\wamp64\www\FMS\welcome.php on line 5
```

Comment: What's the problem you think you're having?

Comment: Notice:Undefined index: 'name'  in C. on line 4

Comment: Show us your URL where error occurs.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp64\www\FMS\welcome.php on line 4

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\wamp64\www\FMS\welcome.php on line 5

Comment: Add the file names to your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php $\_GET and undefined index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876868/php-get-and-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2):

If this is all on the same page, and it looks like it is, then you need to check that those $_GET vars actually exist before you can echo them:

```
Welcome <?php echo isset( $_GET["name"] ) ? $_GET["name"] : 'Nameless One'; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo isset( $_GET["email"] ) ? $_GET["email"] : 'non-existent'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is telling you that the key of 'name' does not exist in the `$_GET` super global array, because it has not been populated yet, because the form has not been submitted.

If you have a page with a form, let's call it welcome.php, and it contains the following code.

```
<html>
    <body>
     <form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Then the forms action is telling the server to have welcome_get.php process the form. If this is what you want, then you need welcome_get.php in the same folder as welcome.php and you put this code in welcome_get.php

```
      <html>
            <body>
        if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {  
                Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
               Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
            }

        </body>
            </html>
```

If you want the form script welcome.php to process itself and display the message change the action type of the form to # like this. The code below will only show welcome after the user submits the form, the Welcome text appears below the form. This prevents the errors

```
    <html>
    <body>
     <form action="#" method="get">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
     if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {  
        Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
       Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>
    }
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Also in php you will pretty much always want to check if a value exists in an array before trying to use it or else you get a notice/warning. On a production server, the settings ignore minor missing array values, it is just best practice to check like so.

if(isset($array['key'])){ 
    $value = $array['key'];
}

Comment: Thanks guys.Sadly i'm quite new in Php. My idea is that i have to enter my name and email on the form so that when i run the code i get the Welcome message and email address notification. It still doesn't  work. On clicking submit button i actually get the HTTP 404 not found error(Web page cannot be found)

Comment: @SMAMRulz. In your form you have `welcomen-get.php`,but the error message display `welcome.php`. I think that's probably the source of the 404.

Comment: use this for the action to have the forms submit to the same php script as the page.
<form action="#" method="get">
Simply change the action to # tells the script to submit to itself and then you process it the same page

Comment: <form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">  The action part of the form html tag tells the current page script what file should process it when the form is submitted. Your form tells the server welcome_get.php should process the form. If you make a welcome_get.php file in the same folder as this form file it will process the form. welcome_get.php you could access your $_GET array variables and output a message

Comment: Robert, please use the preview window before posting - all of your paragraph text was formatted as code here.

Comment: So how do i indicate here that a certain user gave me the helpful answer?

Comment: I tried formatting it, every time I got one code section formatted it complained about another so I  formatted the whole thing and if finally shut up about the code formatting. Not sure what else I could have done. It was ok with 1 then 2 sections, 3 not so much. I'll try harder next time

Comment: Do you know the general rules of proper HTML formatting? If not, that's where you should begin.

Comment: who me or the OP?

Comment: If you are talking to me you could at least address me to make it clear. And if it this is what you are talking about. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  Then you could simply have posted that.  That would have been more helpful than rudely saying. "
 
Do you know the general rules of proper HTML formatting? If not, that's where you should begin. "

Comment: Sorry everyone I falsely assumed that highlighting the code i wanted formated and using You can also select text and press CTRL+K to toggle indenting as code. Would work. My bad. Thanks for the helpful comments.