# How to write RewriteRules for .htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a PHP file named as `otp.php`.

When URL in the URL bar is

```
http://localhost/college/otp/MTA=/teacher
```

It should be treated as

```
http://localhost/college/otp.php?user=MTA=&role=teacher
```

For this, I created `.htaccess` file in *http://localhost/college/*:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^otp/?$    otp.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^otp/[A-Za-z-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    otp.php?user=$1&role=$2    [NC,L]
```

But, `otp.php` file says:

> Notice: Undefined index: role in C:\wamp\www\college\otp.php on line
>   11
>
> Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\wamp\www\college\otp.php on line
>   11

#### UPDATE

When URL in the URL bar is

```
http://localhost/college/otp/MTA/teacher
```

It should be treated as

```
http://localhost/college/otp.php?user=MTA&role=teacher
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I think the following question should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876868/php-get-and-undefined-index

Comment: The question you linked is not related to me, as I am using `isset` in my codes, main problem is in `.htaccess` file. @Abhineet

Comment: `[A-Za-z-]+` does _not_ match the `=` you show in your example.So the rule does not get applied.

Comment: Then how to use it?

Comment: You could try this rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^\=([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /college/otp.php?user=$1&role=$2 [L]`

Comment: @Qirel I tried `RewriteRule    ^\=([^/]*)/([^/]*)$                   otp.php?user=$1&role=$2 [L]` but it didn't gave results. Same Notice.

Comment: @arkascha any updates?

Comment: Why do you ask _me_ for updates? I pointed out why the rule does not get applied, what explains why your get the notice. There is nothing I can do about that, _you_ need to change that rule.

Comment: @arkascha So, how will be my new rule? I tried Qirel's answer but it didn't work. I asked for the update as I thought you're able to clear the issue.

Comment: You yourself implemented a rule with is meant to capture `MTA` from the URL `MTA=/teacher` (I assume that), but the pattern `[A-Za-z-]+` you use is unable to match the "=". So you need to change that pattern you yourself implemented. Why can't you simply do that?

Comment: It has the same notice when I try `http://localhost/college/otp/MTA/teacher` @arkascha

Comment: Did you make sure that your dynamic configuration file is considered and applied _at all_ by your http server? How did you do that?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. @arkascha

Comment: Dynamic configuration files (".htaccess" style files) are _not_ enabled and considered by the apache http server per default, because they have a lot of disadvantages compared to using the actual http servers host configuration. So my question is: have you enabled it? If so, how did you check that this actually worked?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled. In *httpd.conf* the codes are `<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all denied
</Directory>` and in `phpinfo();` loaded modules --> *mod_rewrite* @arkascha

Comment: `<Directory />` ? Why that? You certainly do _not_ want to expose the whole server side file system to http clients! But that is another question... Next thing to check is if the file can be read by the http server process. So what are the file system permissions and what account is your http server operated as? Another way to tackle such issues is to monitor the http servers error log file (you need to do that anyway if you operate a http server). What does that file reveal what the issue is? An access issue when trying to open that file? Some invalid command inside that file?

Comment: Also: are there any configurations for the `college` directory or location in the configuration?

Comment: I only have one `.htaccess` file: http://localhost/college/.htaccess

Comment: @arkascha, For now, I am running the script (project) in my local computer using *WAMPSERVER*.

Comment: Which does not answer my questions about file permissions (though indeed MS-Windows is much more careless here compared to other systems, so most likely that is not the issue), or the http servers error log file. A last option is to enable rewrite logging to understand exactly what is going on inside your rewriting engine (you will find details on that in the documentation of the apache http server).

Comment: @arkascha I tried `RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^otp/?$    otp.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^otp/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ otp.php?user=$1&role=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]`, it redirected me to www.example.com.

Comment: @Qirel Can you also try to help with Arkascha? [Read this Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933302/in-regex-for-url-rewrite-in-htaccess?noredirect=1#comment98611582_55933302)

Comment: You again completely fail to answer to my questions and suggestions. Why is that?

Comment: Sorry about that, but I am not able to understand what's your question? @arkascha

Comment: The last _update_ to your question suggests that even when you request `http://localhost/college/otp.php?user=MTA&role=teacher` directly you still get these "undefined index" notices from PHP? Can you confirm this? (As that would completely change the focus of your question.)

Comment: Voted to close this question since it is unclear what is actually asked and the OP does not answer to attempts to find out.

Comment: @MrWhite see this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933302/how-to-write-rewriterules-for-htaccess?noredirect=1#comment98870234_56094417) and the [image](https://i.imgur.com/8KtrM0X.png)

Comment: @paran Neither that comment or the image (which I have already seen) answer my question relating to the recent "update" to your question. Isn't it easier just to answer my question? What happens when you request `http://localhost/college/otp.php?user=MTA&role=teacher` directly? Do you get the expected response, or do you still get "undefined index" notices? The update to your question suggests that you still get these _errors_, however, that really makes no sense and changes the focus of this question.

Comment: @MrWhite It does work when I request `http://localhost/college/otp.php?user=MTA&role=teacher`, see this [image](https://i.imgur.com/pFgRwHX.png)

Comment: Also works when I request `http://localhost/jainvidhya/otp?user=MTA&role=teacher` @MrWhite

Comment: My *otp.php* file: 
`echo $role = "role ==> <b>".$_GET['role']."</b><br />";
echo $user = "user ==> <b>".$_GET['user']."</b>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `URL:       /college/otp/MTA=/teacher`
> `Target:    /college/otp.php?user=MTA=&role=teacher`
> `.htaccess: /college/.htaccess`
>
> ```
> RewriteRule    ^otp/[A-Za-z-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    otp.php?user=$1&role=$2    [NC,L]
> ```

Your `RewriteRule` *pattern* needs a slight modification to match your example URL, since it will currently fail on the `=` in `MTA=`. (Although I've just noticed that the "update" to your question does not show a `=` in the URL?) This pattern also needs to be *capturing* in order for the `$1` to pick it up.

So, the above directive should read something like:

```
 RewriteRule ^otp/([A-Za-z-]+=)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ otp.php?user=$1&role=$2    [NC,L]
```

This assumes that `=` *always* appears at the end of the path segment, as in your initial example (include it inside the character class if it can occur anywhere - although would be a bit confusing). The `NC` flag is probably unnecessary, unless you also need to allow mixed case versions of `otp` (unadvisable). You already allow for mixed case in your regex.

**UPDATE#1:** It seems the second path segment is a base64 encoded string/integer. For this you will need to include digits in the regex and there could be 0, 1 or 2 trailing `=` characters. There is also no need to match a hyphen. For example:

```
 RewriteRule ^otp/([A-Za-z0-9]+={0,2})/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ otp.php?user=$1&role=$2    [NC,L]
```

---

However, the other problem you seem to be experiencing (and the one which you are actually "seeing") is a conflict with MultiViews (part of mod_negotiation). This needs to be disabled for the above mod_rewrite directive to work (in fact, to do anything). If you are not enabling this in `.htaccess` then disable it by including the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

If MultiViews is enabled then when you request `otp` (where a file with the same *basename* exists which would also return an appropriate mime-type) mod_negotiation issues an internal subrequest for `otp.php`. The problem here is that this occurs *before* mod_rewrite, so `otp.php` ends up being called without any URL parameters.

---

*Aside:*

Your code should not be generating these "undefined index" notices. Since this is essentially "user provided data", you should check for it in your script. For example:

```
$role = isset($_GET['role']) ? $_GET['role'] : null;
```

> ```
> RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
> ```

Note that Apache does not support line-end comments, so you should remove the `# Turn on the rewriting engine` text from the first line. (Line-end comments can appear to "work", however, that is just a coincidence with how Apache directives work in general, other times they will result in a 500 internal server error.)

---

**UPDATE#2:**

> If the URL bar has `http://localhost/college/otp.php?user=MTA=&role=teacher`, can it be changed to `http://localhost/college/otp/MTA/teacher`?

Yes this can be done. Although I assume that `MTA=` should appear in both places? (You have `MTA=` in the source and `MTA` in the target, which would presumably corrupt the base64 encoding?) I assume you are already linking to the correct URL internally and this is only to benefit stray requests (search engines, backlinks, etc.?)

You can implement an *external redirect* before the above rewrite, being careful not to redirect the rewritten URL and triggering a redirect loop. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=([A-Za-z0-9]+={0,2})&role=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)
RewriteRule ^(otp)\.php$ /college/$1/%1/%2 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

This is basically the reverse of the *internal rewrite* (that appears later in the `.htaccess` file). The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures that it only triggers for direct requests and not rewritten requests.

Note that since this is an external redirect, you need to include a root-relative URL-path in the *substitution* argument. ie. include the `/college` subdirectory. (Or, you can use a relative *substitution* and set the `RewriteBase` - although you'd only do this if you have several of these directives.)

`$1` is a backreference to the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. always `otp`) and `%1` and `%2` are backreferences to the preceding *CondPattern*, ie. the value of the `user` and `role` URL parameters respectively.

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4+) discards the original query string from the request.

Comment: When I try: `Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^otp/?$    otp.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^otp/([A-Za-z-]+=)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ otp.php?user=$1&role=$2    [NC,L]`, ***404 Not Found***. & when `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^otp/?$    otp.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^otp/([A-Za-z-]+=)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ otp.php?user=$1&role=$2    [NC,L]`, ***same issue***.

Comment: With MultiViews disabled, a 404 response implies the `RewriteRule` is not matching. What URL are you requesting? Do you have have any other directives in this `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files? When you say "same issue" for the second rule block, are you saying that also returns a 404, with the `Options -MultiViews` directive removed?

Comment: Where can `=` appear in the URL path segment? Is it always at the end - if it appears at all? Or can it appear anywhere? eg. `M=TA`?

Comment: I am just **encoding integers** in `base64`, so I think if `=` is there it will be at the end only...

Comment: If you are encoding as base64 then there could be 0, 1 or 2 `=` at the end. You will also need to match digits, which are currently omitted from your regex. So, you will need something like `([A-Za-z0-9]+={0,2})` instead. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Bit of an aside, but why do you need to encode _integers_ as base64 in the URL? Or is that just how the data is coming?

Comment: The data is coming like that only. The last one, If the URL bar has `http://localhost/college/otp.php?user=MTA=&role=teacher`, can it be changed to **`http://localhost/college/otp/MTA=/teacher`**? (Any link for explaining it?)

Comment: I've updated my answer regarding your last part about the reverse operation... redirecting from `http://localhost/college/otp.php?user=MTA=&role=teacher`.

Comment: Ah, you need the QSD flag (I've updated my answer). I assume you are on Apache 2.4? You have `jainvidhya` to `otp` in your comment - is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry for my typos,: `http://localhost/college/otp.php?user=MTA=&role=teacher` changes to **`http://localhost/otp/MTA=/teacher?user=MTA=&role=teacher`** and gives ***404 Not Found***. And after your last update, it changes to **`http://localhost/otp/MTA=/teacher`**, but it **should** change to, ***`http://localhost/college/otp/MTA=/teacher`***.

Comment: Ah, yes, you'll need to explicitly include the `/college` subdirectory in the _substitution_ string. ie. `/college/$1/%1/%2` (as opposed to `/$1/%1/%2`). I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[This tool](https://regex101.com/r/lENMeI/1) might help you to write correct expressions for your RewriteRules. Maybe, this expression would give you an idea, where the problems may be:

```
(.*otp)\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+=)\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)
```

[image]

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) helps you to visualizes your expressions for the RewriteRule:

[image]

Then, you can write a RewriteRule, maybe something similar to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} localhost  [NC]
    RewriteRule    (.*otp)\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+=)\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)  $1.php?user=$2&role=$3  [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

You might want to clear your browser history, every time that you modify your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I tried `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} localhost  [NC]
    RewriteRule    (.*otp)\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+=)\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)  $1.php?user=$2&role=$3  [NC,L]
</IfModule>`, **also** *without `<IfModule></IfModule>`* but then also has same notice (*cleared browser history too*). [see image](https://i.imgur.com/8KtrM0X.png)

Comment: The Code:- `echo $role = $_GET['role'];`, the error:- ***Notice: Undefined index: role in C:\wamp\www\college\otp.php on line 11***. Though the *role* is defined in the url bar: `http://localhost/jainvidhya/otp/MTA=/teacher` i.e : *http://localhost/college/otp.php?user=MTA=&role=teacher*